# printf doesnt work in Eclipse with CDT and cygwin gcc

Tags: eclipse, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I installed cygwin in my eclipse and wrote a simple hello world program.

It compiles correctly and the executable is also produced. But on running the program, no output is produced on console.

A message make: Nothing to be done for "all"

appears and vanishes off from console.

Can anybody please let me know the cause and solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem in cdt.

[image]

do you run as the local c/c++?
I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may be not actually running the program, just compiling it. `Nothing to be done for "all"` appears when you are compiling a program that's already compiled - there's nothing to do.

If you are in fact running your program, then please provide your code, or try adding a sleep function after printing the text - it may simply be happening too fast to see.

Comment: Is there any other way to stop the it from vanishing like using getch()? As I'm using gcc I'm not able to use getch.

Comment: On Windows, call `system("pause");`. This will cause `"press any key to continue..."` to appear.

Comment: I tried it. But not working,, even with sleep or with system("pause")